# How are weather intensity scales created?

Tags: meteorology, severe-weather, tornado, mesoscale-meteorology, scale

I am interested in the development of scales to measure extreme weather.

For example, the **Enhanced Fujita Scale** for measuring the intensity of tornadoes, etc. How were they created? OK sure, I know someone, probably named Fujita, made a scale, but at what point and how did people just decide to go along with it?

Comment: https://www.spc.noaa.gov/faq/tornado/ef-ttu.pdf

Comment: @Catterall Wind speed, Estimated Damage, Rain, Cloud cover and etc all contribute to an Intensity Scale.